# Why does Perl MIME::Base64 insert CR characters before LF characters on decoding Base64-encoded strings when they aren't present in the original data?

Tags: perl, character-encoding, base64

Why does the Perl MIME::Base64 module on decoding Base64-encoded strings insert CR characters before LF characters when they are not present in the original data?

Input: a binary described by the following hex string,

14 15 6A 48 E4 15 6A 32 E5 48 46 13 A5 E3 88 43 18 A6 84 E3 51 3A 8A **0A** 1A 3E E6 84 A6 1A 16 E8 46 84 A1 2E A3 5E 84 8A 4E 1A 35 E1 35 1E 84 A9 8E 46 54 44

This encodes to the Base64-encoded string:

FBVqSOQVajLlSEYTpeOIQximhONROooKGj7mhKYaFuhGhKEuo16Eik4aNeE1HoSpjkZURA==

My Perl script for decoding is

```
use MIME::Base64;
my $bin =  decode_base64('FBVqSOQVajLlSEYTpeOIQximhONROooKGj7mhKYaFuhGhKEuo16Eik4aNeE1HoSpjkZURA==');
open FH, ">test.bin" or die $!;
print FH $bin;
close FH;
```

Output: the resulting file 'test.bin' has the following hex string representation,

14 15 6A 48 E4 15 6A 32 E5 48 46 13 A5 E3 88 43 18 A6 84 E3 51 3A 8A **0D 0A** 1A 3E E6 84 A6 1A 16 E8 46 84 A1 2E A3 5E 84 8A 4E 1A 35 E1 35 1E 84 A9 8E 46 54 44

Note the hex digits in bold highlighting the additional '0D' character that has been inserted before '0A' where it was not present in the original data.

I'm using Perl v5.14.2 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on Windows, you will need to open that filehandle in binary mode to prevent your line-endings from being munged.

```
open FH, ">test.bin" or die $!;
binmode FH;
```

You can do that all at once using IO layers, and also using a lexical filehandle which is better practice than a package symbol like `FH`:

```
open my $fh, '>:raw', 'test.bin' or die $!;
print { $fh } $bin;
```

For more, check out

- [perldoc perlio](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html)
- [perldoc perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html)

Comment: Great, that solved the problem! Thanks for the info on how to set the binary mode using the two types of file handle.